# FragmentPagerAdapter crashes with getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-viewpager

This is code for making `ViewPager`. Error is that view is not found, though view is there.

```
View attachmentBottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.attachment_view_pager_with_tabs, null);
            BottomSheetDialog attachmentBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
            attachmentBottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            attachmentBottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams attachmentSheetParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    displayMetrics.heightPixels);

        ViewPager viewPager = attachmentBottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerAttachment);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                AttachmentTabsFragment attachmentTabsFragment = new AttachmentTabsFragment();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        bundle.putString(KEY_ATTACHMENT_FRAGMENT_NAME, "Image");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        bundle.putString(KEY_ATTACHMENT_FRAGMENT_NAME, "Video");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        bundle.putString(KEY_ATTACHMENT_FRAGMENT_NAME, "GIF");
                        break;
                }
                attachmentTabsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return attachmentTabsFragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Image";
                    case 1:
                        return "Video";
                    case 2:
                        return "GIF";
                }
                return "";
            }
        });

        TabLayout tabLayout = attachmentBottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.varun);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        window.setWindowAnimations(R.style.attachment_bottom_sheet_dialog_animation);
        attachmentBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(attachmentBottomSheetView, attachmentSheetParams);
        attachmentBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

Error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0901b9 (com.example.circle:id/viewPagerAttachment) for fragment AttachmentTabsFragment{98eb499 #7 id=0x7f0901b9 android:switcher:2131296697:0}

When I tried replacing `getChildFragmentManager()` with `getFragmentManger()` I get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ViewPager` exists in a `BottomSheetDialog` its not the part of Fragment. And `BottomSheetDialog` is a `Dialog` not a `Fragment` .

Soloution:- Use [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment) instead of  `BottomSheetDialog`. Then you can access all functionality of a `Fragment`  inside a BottomSheet.

Comment: Then how to set view to that .. for this line  attachmentBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(attachmentBottomSheetView, attachmentSheetParams);

Comment: `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is child of `DialogFragment`. It has its own methods for setting Views. Just follow a tutorial . [Here is one](https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc).